# .htaccess redirect not working for query strings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect olddomain.com with all its sub-pages (and those can have query strings in URLs) to a specific page on new domain:

> newdomain.com/target-page/

Currently I'm using this code in .htaccess of olddomain.com:

```
RewriteEngine On
rewritecond %{http_host} ^olddomain.com
rewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.newdomain.com/target-page/ [R=301,L]
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.newdomain.com/target-page/
```

It works fine except for some instances where there's a query string in URL.

For example:

```
http://www.olddomain.com/home.php?pd=index
```

Redirects to:

```
https://www.newdomain.com/target-page/?pd=index
```

and I need it to be just:

```
https://www.newdomain.com/target-page/
```

What is interesting, a page like this:

```
http://www.olddomain.com/?page_id=503
```

Redirects fine to:

```
https://www.newdomain.com/target-page/
```

How do I make sure everything on olddomain.com is redirected to newdomain.com/target-page/ including query strings, etc.?

Thanks!

Comment: First you’re saying that it currently redirects to `/target-page/?pd=index` and you need it to be just `/target-page/`, but at the end of the question you ask how you can _keep_ the original query string - now which one is it …?

Comment: Query strings get added as /target-page/?pd=index, while I don't want that, and need everything (with query strings or not) to redirect to /target-page/ only.

Comment: Add a question mark at the end of the rewrite target, that should suppress any existing query string from being applied. `rewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.newdomain.com/target-page/? [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a rewrite rule with a query string match condition, such as:
This will redirect ALL requests from www.olddomain.com to newdomain.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^alt\.olddomian\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

Code was taken from the official [mod_rewrite manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost)

UPDATE: This will redirect your specific URL to another domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =olddomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(p=1&preview=true)
RewriteRule ^$ http://newdomaincom/?%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately it didn't work in my case. Query strings are still being added to target page URL.